# How to create and organize non UI related elements using the MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm creating a WPF application using the MVVM design pattern. I've only recently started learning both, but have a solid grasp on how the basics work.

The application will have classes that are not UI related, such as a networking thread and message handler, and a class to save and load settings.

These elements of the program don't have a clear connection with the UI. How should they be created and initialized? These are "application wide" services that will not fit a particular ViewModel, and don't feel like a Model either.

Is there a correct way to do this? What should "own" and create these objects? (The ViewModel, or rather make them static and create themselves?)

Here is a diagram of the MVVM model, with a few adjustments to show what I am looking for: (Highlighted text and purple box)

When a "user has joined" message is received the the server, the service will send an event to the model that has subscribed to it, notifying it of the new user. The ViewModel will see this change, and add the user's name to the UI.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Jo1mWDk.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have services that are linked to a certain functionality of a UI. (Only the main windows uses them, for example) And there can also be services that are shared between many windows.

For the first scenario, I usually instantiate the services in my ViewModels.
For application wide services, I'd rather create the instances in App.xaml.cs and pass the reference to my viewmodel.

Here is an example from one of my projects.

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    ConnectionManager connMan = new ConnectionManager();
    MainViewModel mvm = new MainViewModel(connMan);
    new MainWindow(mvm).ShowDialog();

    // TODO: save settings, etc. here

    this.Shutdown();
}
```

If your services do not rely on any state information, you could use static classes as well. And that is what I usually use for settings management, for example.

**Edit:** For the example you've posted, you have to ask yourself this question:

> Who is responsible for creating and maintaining the network manager object?

If it is the ViewModel, it can host the object inside itself. If it is created by an external object, you would pass it to the ViewModel.  There are pros and cons to either approach and I don't have enough information to suggest you one of them right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a DI Container and register your services with it. It is then a matter of personal preferences if you use Dependency Injection or use the DI Container as a mere Service Locator.

The basic idea behind a service locator is to have an object that knows how to get hold of all of the services that an application might need. So simply speaking ServiceLocator is a singleton Registry.

The basic idea of the Dependency Injection is to have a separate object, an assembler, that populates a field in the lister class with an appropriate implementation.

A good implemantion is the [Microsoft Unity Container](https://unity.codeplex.com). You can use it as an DI container or a Service Locator.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, try to keep a List (eg `ObservablleCollection<T>`) in the `ViewModel`, and model-specific data type like `Person`, `User` in Model.

Then create separate namespaces such as `Workers`, `Helpers` or `Managers`, which are *static* classes that are only responsible for their specific area. For example: `Workers / Sql / SqlWorker`, `Workers / Network / NetworkWorker`.

Later in the `ViewModel`, call these methods in the appropriate commands.

I think it would be a simple and advanced solution, since workers will not interfere with each other (if only via abstract interfaces), besides they will not be connection to the UI.